# Why does the outside fan stop but the blower fan continues to run?

Tags: hvac

We can have the thermostat set on 76 but wont stay 76 in house. Will come on when temperature is 79 in the house.

Comment: Thermostats don't keep a home at exactly the set temperature. They turn the heat/cool on at the set temp +/- a couple degrees, and turn the heat/cool off at the set temp +/- a couple degrees. Some thermostats allow you to adjust the range at which they react.

Answer (score 1):

I think the outdoor unit fan turning off while the AC is still running is normal - I know that happens quite often in my own home (and my previous home), and the AC has always worked fine.

As for the temperature, how new is your thermostat?  In my current house, I have a thermostat from about 30 years ago (one of those dial-style thermostats), and while it works fine in general, the temperature it's set to has very little relation to the actual temperature in the house.  If it's cold, we turn the thermostat up a little, and vice versa, and it works out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the coils aren't frozen.
Also look for water clog in the drip pan.
Or could need a shot of freon.

Where are you located?
Is the problem new?  Recently working suddenly not?
Has AC been on a lot lately?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the setpoint and the activation temperature is called the "Deadband". 3° F is not uncommon for generic thermostats.  Your thermostat probably calls for cooling at 79 and runs until it's at or near 76, right?  This is its strategy to prevent turning the AC on and off too often, which is called "Short Cycling" and causes increased wear and tear.  You have two options to avoid your house being 79° F, either lower the setpoint so the deadband doesn't hit 79, or get a different thermostat (they are typically not adjustable) with a smaller deadband.